# Implementing google maps on windows 8 metro apps

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8

[Google Maps on windows phone](http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/)

The above mentioned link enabled a developer to implement Google maps on windows 8 metro apps
but through 
New project>installed>templates>JavaScript>store

whereas I wanted the same to work in Visual C# >Windows Store

Any idea how can I implement the project in the above mentioned link into my store app

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a C# class library project and import the dll files into your javascript project. You have simply to start from javascript your entry point.

That was the answer i get from microsoft hellas windows store head.

Comment: cant I use the javascript "project" as a self designed control and embed it somewhere in the xaml of my Windows store C# project

Comment: Is there any way I can navigate to the default.html in the javascript project through a control(possibly webview) and using something like
Control.navigate(.......)

Comment: I suppose that you could usewebbrowser control and call method navigate to and insert as parameter HTML5 + JS code of your application .... i am afraid tha it would be a litle buggy and slower than xaml.

Comment: You must have noticed in the default.html some WinJS references.
While referring to those I am encountering some gross errors
what are these, where in my system I can found them

Comment: Solved the problem
disabled script debugging in the debug>options and settings

Comment: I am able to display Google Maps in a WebView control in Windows8 Store app
the only thing left is that I am not able to modify the dimensions of the iframe in the webView control